# How to loop inside a variable

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have an array containing column names of a table i want to create which i got from an excel sheet.

I tried something like this

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$month."-".date('Y')."(
    ".foreach($tableColumnNames as $columnName){
         echo $columnName." VARCHAR(200) NULL,";
      }
."
)";
```

It returns error saying `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach'` same thing with while loops

How can i create Table with column names i have in an array. And How can i set each column data type unique (INT,VARCHAR,..)

Comment: you shouldent use echo, you want to concatenate the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to build the sql string like so:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$month."-".date('Y')."(";

    foreach($tableColumnNames as $columnName){
         $sql .= $columnName." VARCHAR(200) NULL,";
      }
$sql=rtrim($sql,',');//remove last comma
$sql .=")";
```

Comment: How can i remove comma(,) from sql last column name else it give me errors.

Comment: refresh, i added that in

Comment: it removes comma(,) from whole string not just from last column

Comment: are you sure you put it in the right place? it is outside the foreach

Comment: Sorry My mistake.. it was inside loop. Now everything works fine