# mysqli_query returns false because values contain space charcter

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting data from a excel sheet but i receive error and it looks like it is breaking because the value contain a space character in between. As far as i remember space characters allowed in `VARCHAR(200)`

This is the code i am using

```
//CREATE SQL QUERY FOR INSERTING DATA IN DATABASE
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$month."_".$year."(";
    foreach($sheetData[1] as $columnName){
        $sql .= preg_replace('#[ ]#', '_',$columnName). ",";
    }
    $sql = rtrim($sql, ',');//REMOVES COMMA FROM END OF THE STRING
    $sql .= ")";
    //
    $sql .= " VALUES((";
    for($i=2;$i < count($sheetData);$i++){
        foreach($sheetData[$i] as $columnName){
            $sql .= $columnName.",";
        }
        $sql = rtrim($sql,',');//
        $sql .= "),";
    }
    $sql = rtrim($sql,',');//
    $sql .= ")";
    echo $sql;
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

After loops this is how my `SQL QUERY` look

```
INSERT INTO December_2015(S_No,Zone,State,City2,VM_Town,Distibutor_Code,Distributor_Name,Dealer_Code,Dealer_Name,Category,Address,Location,Contact,Mobile_No,Visit_1,Visit_2,Visit_3,Visit_4,Visit_5,Visit_6) VALUES( (1,South,Telanagana,Hyderabad,Y,1006704,Sai Santhoshi Enterprises,TG000999,Sree Laxmi Mobiles,A,F4,anthem Arcade,gujarathi Galli,koti ,Koti,Rajesh,8790575680,7-Nov,18-Nov,28-Nov))
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Santhoshi Enterprises,TG000999,Sree Laxmi Mobiles,A,F4,anthem Arcade,gujarathi G' at line 1

It says near `'Santhoshi Enterprises ... '` before that there is a space character

Comment: Do you have single quotes around your varchar values?

Comment: Why use the month and year as the tablename instead of having them as columns in a general table?

Comment: You need to wrap any string values being inserted into your table with quotes.

Comment: You'd do better to have a single table, partitioned by year and month, and to specify the columns explicitly rather than relying on the ones in the spreadsheet being correct. You also really should be using a prepared statement rather than dynamic SQL; even if you aren't worried about SQL injection, the prepared statement will provide a "Bozo filter" against misformatted values in the sheet, and will automagically handle proper quoting of string values.

Comment: yes it was quotes problem figured out just after posting this question.

i am creating table name with month-year because every month i will receive new data with new columns/rows. my client will upload a excel sheet every month which contains information what to do whole month

Answer (score 0):

You have two "(" instead of one after "VALUES"

Answer (score 0):

[Akash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2803557/akash-kumar),
Didn't you asked a question just a while ago regarding same/similar code with a different error you got, here at: [How to loop inside a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859539/how-to-loop-inside-a-variable) ?!

By the looks of it in general you write messy code, and you are having trouble reading/understanding the error messages. So I'm gonna guess you are new at this.

**Here are some good reads for you:**

- [Top 15+ Best Practices for Writing Super Readable Code](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/top-15-best-practices-for-writing-super-readable-code--net-8118)
- [PHP the right way](http://www.phptherightway.com/)

When all said and done, here is your code broken down into more readable segments:

```
// prepare dummy data
$month = date('M');
$year = date('Y');
$sheetData = array(
    array('data00', 'data01')
    ,array('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6')
    ,array('data20', "data21")
    ,array('data30', 'data31')
    ,array('data40', 'data41')
);

// prepare vars
$tableName = "{$month}_{$year}";
$dataCount = count($sheetData);

// prepare columns
$columnsSQL = "";
foreach ($sheetData[1] as $columnName) {
    // wrap with ` ticks
    $columnsSQL .= '`'. preg_replace('#[ ]#', '_', $columnName).'`'.',';
}
$columnsSQL = rtrim($columnsSQL, ',');

// prepare values
$valuesSQL = "";
for ($i=2;$i < $dataCount;$i++) {
    foreach($sheetData[$i] as $columnValue){
        $valuesSQL .= "'{$columnValue}', ";
    }
}
$valuesSQL = rtrim($valuesSQL, ', ');

$SQL = "
INSERT INTO {$tableName}( {$columnsSQL} )
VALUES ( {$valuesSQL} )";
```

At the end you end up with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Nov_2015( `col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,`col5`,`col6` )
VALUES ( 'data20', 'data21', 'data30', 'data31', 'data40', 'data41' )
```

***Additional note and tips:***

- Considering that you said you are reading data from excel sheet... Never trust input data without some tests/checks/validation. Not just because of security but stability and in general you don't want things breaking.
  Those excel tables could be manually made which automatically means its prone for human error, so you can't be always 100% sure what are you gonna get.
- Consider using PDO and prepared statements *(security reasons, but also good practice)*